Implementing a Global Observable in Qiskit v1.1.0
In the following article the authors consider a quantum autoencoder in their numerical results, near to the equation (22). In more detail,  the authors consider a bipartite quantum system $A B$ composed of $n_{\mathrm{A}}$ and $n_{\mathrm{B}}$ qubits, respectively, and let $\left\{p_\mu,\left|\psi_\mu\right\rangle\right\}$ be an ensemble of pure states on $A B$. The goal of the quantum autoencoder is to train a gate sequence $V(\theta)$ to compress this ensemble into the $A$ subsystem, such that one can recover each state $\left|\psi_\mu\right\rangle$ with high fidelity from the information in subsystem $A$. One can think of $B$ as the "trash" since it is discarded after the action of $V(\boldsymbol{\theta})$.
To quantify the degree of data compression, the author's proposal is to use a cost function of the form:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& C_{\mathrm{G}}^{\prime}=1-\operatorname{Tr}\left[|\mathbf{0}\rangle\langle\mathbf{0}| \rho_{\mathrm{B}}^{\mathrm{out}}\right] \\
& =\operatorname{Tr}\left[O_{\mathrm{G}}^{\prime} V(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \rho_{\mathrm{AB}}^{\mathrm{in}} V(\boldsymbol{\theta})^{\dagger}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\rho_{\mathrm{AB}}^{\mathrm{in}}=\sum_\mu p_\mu\left|\psi_\mu\right\rangle\left\langle\psi_\mu\right|$ is the ensemble-average input state, $\rho_{\mathrm{B}}^{\text {out }}=\sum_\mu p_\mu \operatorname{Tr}_{\mathrm{A}}\left[\left|\psi^{\prime}\right\rangle\left\langle\psi^{\prime}\right|\right]$ is the ensemble-average trash state, and $\left|\psi^{\prime}\right\rangle=V(\boldsymbol{\theta})\left|\psi_\mu\right\rangle$ The previous equation makes it clear that $C_{\mathrm{G}}^{\prime}$ has the form in equation (6), and $O_{\mathrm{G}}^{\prime}=\mathbb{1}_{\mathrm{AB}}-\mathbb{1}_{\mathrm{A}} \otimes|\mathbf{0}\rangle\langle\mathbf{0}|$ is a global observable of the form in (10). Hence, according to Corollary $1, C_{\mathrm{G}}^{\prime}$ exhibits a barren plateau for large $n_{\mathrm{B}}$. (Specifically, Corollary 1 applies in this context when $n_{\mathrm{A}}<n_{\mathrm{B}}$ ). As a result, large-scale data compression, where one is interested in discarding large numbers of qubits, will not be possible with $C_{\mathrm{G}}^{\prime}$.
What is a good approach to implement the global observable in this context using Qiskit v1.1.0?

To implement $O'_G$, just use numpy:
import numpy as np

n = 2      # Size of A
m = 3      # Size of B
k = n + m  # Size of AB

I_AB = np.eye(2**k,2**k)
I_A = np.eye(2**n,2**n)
Zr_B = np.zeros((2**m,2**m))
Zr_B[0,0] = 1

OG = I_AB - np.kron(I_A,Zr_B)

You can then do things like calculating the expectation value of a state with respect to $O'_G$ using qiskit's quantum_info or the Estimator primitive.
With quantum info:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector, Operator

# Arbitrary circuit to generate |ψ⟩
qc = QuantumCircuit(k)
qc.h(k-1)
qc.cx(k-1,k-2)

for qb in range(m,0,-1):
    qc.cx(qb,qb-1)


# Compute ⟨ψ|OG|ψ⟩
sv = Statevector(qc)
OG_op = Operator(OG)
exp_val = sv.expectation_value(OG_op)

Using the Estimator from qiskit:
from qiskit.primitives.statevector_estimator import StatevectorEstimator
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp

OG_pauli = SparsePauliOp.from_operator(OG_op)

estimator = StatevectorEstimator()
exp_val = estimator.run([(qc,OG_pauli)]).result()[0].data.evs


Regarding your definition of Zr_B, I get this piece Zr_B = np.zeros((2**m,2**m)) but this piece Zr_B[0,0] = 1 or needs further clarification.

Zr_B represents the matrix $|\mathbf{0}\rangle \langle \mathbf{0}|$, which is the outer product of the all-zeros state in the subspace of $B$ (i.e. $|0\rangle^{\otimes m} = [1 ; 0 \dots 0 ; 0]^\mathsf{T}$) with itself. This outer product results in an all-zeros $2^m \times 2^m$ matrix with the exception of a $1$ in the first entry of the matrix. If this is not clear let me know; I'll edit the post above and add the expressions I just described.

Makes sense that print(OG_pauli) produce: SparsePauliOp(['IIIII', 'IIIIZ', 'IIIZI', 'IIIZZ', 'IIZII', 'IIZIZ', 'IIZZI', 'IIZZZ'],               coeffs=[ 0.875+0.j, -0.125+0.j, -0.125+0.j, -0.125+0.j, -0.125+0.j, -0.125+0.j,  -0.125+0.j, -0.125+0.j])? The last two Pauli-strings of the list puzzle me regrading the correctness of the result.

I understand that the list of strings ['IIIII', 'IIIIZ', 'IIIZI', 'IIIZZ', 'IIZII', 'IIZIZ', 'IIZZI', 'IIZZZ'] seems to be complete for the B subsystem in the z basis, but this is enough to assume that the implementation is correct? Any other checks to do?
